# Changing the answer points using exams

Tags: exam

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\title{2023 Non-Calc}
\author{ccd1pga }
\date{May 2023}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in}{\centering
 Answer the questions in the spaces provided on the
question sheets. If you run out of room for an answer,
continue on the back of the page.}}}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.1in}
\makebox[\textwidth]{Name and section:\enspace\hrulefill}
\vspace{0.2in}
\makebox[\textwidth]{Instructor’s name:\enspace\hrulefill}

\begin{questions} %Start of all questions
\pointsinmargin
\noaddpoints
\question[10]
\begin{parts}
\nopointsinmargin
\addpoints
\part[5] How do I do this?
\end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

but I want "how do I get this? ............................(5)"

for example, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By checking the doc of the `exam` [package](https://ctan.gutenberg-asso.fr/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf), I found in sec 4.3.1 "Where the points will be printed":

`the command \pointsinrightmargin will cause the point values to be set in the right margin,`

I modified your MWE:

```
\begin{parts}
    \pointsinrightmargin
    \addpoints
    \part[5] How do I do this?
\end{parts}
```